# Seems Ansible failed to get the temp files

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible failed while running the tasks and referring file/folder not exists in the ansible temp folder of a target machine. It has been working fine and not sure why all of sudden it stopped working

```
changed :   false
module_stderr   :   Shared connection to 10.131.132.11 closed.\r\n
module_stdout   :   Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1662460628.845051-105063944436404/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 113, in <module>\r\n    try:\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1662460628.845051-105063944436404/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 98, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    json_params = f.read()\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py\", line 321, in mkdtemp\r\n    dir = gettempdir()\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py\", line 265, in gettempdir\r\n    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py\", line 212, in _get_default_tempdir\r\n    (\"No usable temporary directory found in %s\" % dirlist))\r\nIOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/root']\r\n
msg :   MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error
rc  :   1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by checking the permissions if they changed.

I think the disk is probably full. I had the same issue and it was the case.

You can type df -h

Also you can verify the inode.

You can type df -i